# jquery plugin easyPieChart directive for angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am trying to write a directive for [jquery easy pie charts](http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/).

Following the tutorials, this is my code so far ..

```
angular.module('ysf.easyPieChart', []).directive('easyPieChart', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        scope: {
            percent: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            support._debug(elem.easyPieChart, 'element value');
            support._debug(scope.percent, 'scope value');
            //support._debug(this, 'this');
            $(elem.easyPieChart).easyPieChart();
        }
    }

});
```

and this is how i am calling it from my template

```
<div class='easyPieChart' percent='73'>73</div>
```

1.it does draw a circle, but it is not where it should be.
2. it doesn't fill me right amount of percentage.

the chrome console gives me this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'createDocumentFragment' of null
```

thnakyou.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Cool. Then write an answer and mark it as resolved.

Comment: answered ... how can i mark it resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.0.0 the [angular directive](https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart/blob/master/src/angular.directive.js) `easypiechart` were added.

https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart

Answer (score 0):

this is how the code should be, the element is called using elem[0]

```
angular.module('ysf.easyPieChart', []).directive('easyPieChart', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        scope: {
            percent: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            support._debug(elem.easyPieChart, 'element value');
            support._debug(scope.percent, 'scope value');
            //support._debug(this, 'this');
            $(elem[0]).easyPieChart();
        }
    }

});
```